# preventDefault react on submit form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, dom-events, react-bootstrap

I'm working on a login form in react and I have problems preventing the default behavior of the form.
My code:

```
 _onSubmit: function(e) {
    alert("llego1!");
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("llego2!");
    this.setState({ errors: [] });
    var email = this.state.emailValue.trim();
    var password = this.state.passValue.trim();
    if ( !email || !password) {
      return;
    }
    console.log("onSubmit");
    SessionActionCreators.login(email, password);
  },

render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this._onSubmit} style={formStyle}>
          <Input type="text" placeholder="Email" value={this.state.emailValue} onChange={this._EmailChange}/>
          <Input type="password" placeholder="Password" value={this.state.passValue} onChange={this._PassChange}/>
          <ButtonInput type="submit" value="Login" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The first and the second alerts won't trigger, meaning that the function is probably not being called correctly but I read in the docs that `onSubmit` is supported, I am also using react-bootstrap on my form. The default behavior of the form (a get request to the server) is still being carried out, any help would be great.

Edit: I am using React.createClass

Edit2: Tried using `<button type="submit">Login</button>`, still default behavior.

Comment: are you using `es6 classes` or `React.createClass` to create the component?

Comment: Have you tried Button instead of ButtonInput?

Comment: What does your `<ButtonInput />` look like?

Comment: I shall try Button @JanKlimo . ButtonInput is a react-bootstrap component,you can check it here : https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#forms

Comment: Do you have errors in console?

Comment: in the server console, i only get GET requests to the default route,  the browser console doesn't seem to show anything i can't see as an error,but i am not the best user of the browser tool.

Comment: Can you reproduce this error in a JSBin? http://jsbin.com/caheferuli/edit?html,js,output I tried but it works as expected.

Comment: @frammnm created a jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/uubu3k22/). It works there.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question the code works correctly i had a configuration issue that got fixed after fixin another file on the working directory.